# Third Rock from the Sun S02E22: "Will work for Dick": What music is Nina listening to?

Tags: music-identification, third-rock-from-the-sun

In *Third Rock from the Sun*, S02E22: "Will work for Dick", at around the 18 minute mark, when Dick barges into her home, Nina is relaxing listening to some kind of Jazzy music. We only hear about 30 seconds. What is the piece? Thanks!

Link to sound clip: https://sndup.net/8jq4

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is there any way you can provide a link to the music you're talking about?  It's asking a lot to expect everyone wanting to help you to go and find it themselves; you'll get a far better response if you provide all the necessary details yourself.

Comment: If you or your friend have an iPhone, Siri might be able to tell you: https://www.howtogeek.com/699639/how-to-identify-music-with-your-iphone-or-ipad/ (Google Assistant probably does a similar thing on Android)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Even if Google Assistant can't do that, there's still the Shazam app, available for free from the Google Play store. (I have no affiliation with Shazam.)

Comment: Thank you for the Shazam hint. I downloaded the app and tried it, but it gave up and said No Result.

Comment: https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x24geit

Comment: I don't see any credit given for it, so it's likely an original composition by the music department.

Comment: Oh yeah: “We only hear about 30 seconds” — I think it’s more like 3 seconds, Shazam usually needs more than that.